# Retention on unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, compliance-center

There is a lot of good stuff in SharePoint online on retention on items according to modified date etc. But is there any services or features for unique permissions? An example could be remove a unique permission if older than 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box.  You'd have to develop something to do this, if possible.  I mean, I can think of a way to do it via a timer job looking at unique permissions, but it would need to look at every web in the farm, so I'd wonder how it would perform.  SharePoint retention policies are based on items.  Permissions are a different beast.

Comment: Thanks. I have a working timer job cleaning permissions, but I hoped there would be something new with the compliance suite.